# Finding PCAP certificate validity dates

Tags: python, client-certificates, pyshark

I have a piece of code that will return the validity dates for the last certificate listed in a tls.handshake.type == 11 packet.  I want to pull all the certificates within the packet and check the validity dates for them all.  Here is the code snippet I currently have.  I am using pyshark.

```
def get_certificate_expiry_tls(pcap_file,destination=""):
    capture = pyshark.FileCapture(pcap_file, display_filter='tls.handshake.type == 11')

    found = False
    for packet in capture:
        dest_ip = ip_version(packet)
        if (destination !="" and dest_ip == destination) or destination == "":
            cert_hex = packet.tls.handshake_certificate
            certificate_bytes = bytes.fromhex(cert_hex.replace(":", "").replace(" ", ""))
            certificate = x509.load_der_x509_certificate(certificate_bytes, default_backend())

            # Extract certificate details
            issuer = certificate.issuer
            cert_sn = certificate.serial_number
            not_before = datetime.strptime(str(certificate.not_valid_before), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
            not_after = datetime.strptime(str(certificate.not_valid_after), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
            days_left = (not_after - datetime.now()).days
            too_early = False
            too_late = False
            if not_before > datetime.now():
                too_early = True
            if datetime.now() > not_after:
                too_late = True

            print(f'Certificate Validity for destination {dest_ip}')
            print(f'Issuer: {issuer}')
            print(f'Serial Number: {cert_sn}')
            if too_early:
                print(f'>>>Not Before: {not_before}<<<')
            else:
                print(f'   Not Before: {not_before}')
            if too_late:
                print(f'>>>Not After: {not_after}<<<')
            else:
                print(f'   Not After: {not_after}')
            print(f'  Days Left: {days_left} days')
            print('---')
            found = True

    if not found:
       print(f'No certificate found on destination {destination}')

    capture.close()
    return()
```

Output looks like this for the certificate found for example:

```
Certificate Validity for destination 40.126.24.146
Issuer: <Name(C=US,O=DigiCert Inc,CN=DigiCert SHA2 Secure Server CA)>
Serial Number: 3287290595213795316696678255992371503
   Not Before: 2023-04-05 00:00:00
   Not After: 2024-04-05 23:59:59
  Days Left: 303 days
---
```

This packet contains two certificates but I can only display the one.
[Wireshark output of packet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lIjJN.png)

I want to display both certificates in the output with their validity date ranges.  The purpose of this code is to quickly identify a certificate that has expired.